# Javascript Contenteditable - set Cursor / Caret to index

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

How would I go a about modifying this([How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div?rq=1)) so it accepts a number index and element and sets the cursor position to that index?

For example:
If I had the paragraph:

```
<p contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

And I called:

```
setCaret($(this).get(0), 3)
```

The cursor would move to index 3 like so:

```
Thi|s is a paragraph.
```

---

I have this but with no luck:

```
function setCaret(contentEditableElement, index)
{
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
    {
        range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.setStart(contentEditableElement,index);
        range.collapse(true);
        selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
        selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
        selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
    }
    else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
    { 
        range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BanQU/4/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an answer adapted from  [Persisting the changes of range objects after selection in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949059/persisting-the-changes-of-range-objects-after-selection-in-html/13950376#13950376). Bear in mind that this is less than perfect in several ways (as is MaxArt's, which uses the same approach): firstly, only text nodes are taken into account, meaning that line breaks implied by `<br>` and block elements are not included in the index; secondly, all text nodes are considered, even those inside elements that are hidden by CSS or inside `<script>` elements; thirdly, consecutive white space characters that are collapsed on the page are all included in the index; finally, IE <= 8's rules are different again because it uses a different mechanism.

```
var setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = null;

if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = function(containerEl, start, end) {
        var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

        while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                if (!foundStart && start >= charIndex && start <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setStart(node, start - charIndex);
                    foundStart = true;
                }
                if (foundStart && end >= charIndex && end <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setEnd(node, end - charIndex);
                    stop = true;
                }
                charIndex = nextCharIndex;
            } else {
                var i = node.childNodes.length;
                while (i--) {
                    nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
} else if (document.selection) {
    setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = function(containerEl, start, end) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);
        textRange.select();
    };
}
```

Comment: I see you've implemented an iterative tree traversal routine. But AFAIK those browsers that support `getSelection` support `document.createTreeWalker` too, [which is faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes). So we should go for rit.

Comment: @MaxArt: Yes, I've never come across a browser that supports Range but not TreeWalker (both being from DOM Level 2, that makes sense). I improved those tests and made a jsPerf that suggests you're right about speed, in most browsers. http://jsperf.com/text-node-traversal

Comment: I'm actually surprised that TreeWalker is *slower* in Chrome :| But anyway it saves a bunch of code pain...

Comment: When substituting the code above (http://jsfiddle.net/zQUhV/20/) with your code (http://jsfiddle.net/zQUhV/21/) it doesn't seem to work. Note: the jsfiddle code is built to traverse between the last 2 paragraphs using the arrow keys. It works in the first link but not the second, however the first link breaks when  index and text length are equal, `setCaret(prev.get(0), prev.text().length)`

Comment: @RyanKing: You have a syntax error in the jsFiddle (`?` instead of `{`). http://jsfiddle.net/zQUhV/22/

Comment: ... which it appears was in my code as well :) Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @TimDown, why you've used `end` variable? and how to get it?

Comment: @VedantTerkar: `end` specifies the character offset for the end of the selection. If you want to place the caret and have no selection, use the same value as `start`.

Comment: @TimDown awesome solution. How would you go on about to also take into account line breaks ?

Answer (score 7):

`range.setStart` and `range.setEnd` can be used on *text* nodes, not element nodes. Or else they will raise a DOM Exception. So what you have to do is

```
range.setStart(contentEditableElement.firstChild, index);
```

I don't get what you did for IE8 and lower. Where did you mean to use `index`?

Overall, your code fails if the content of the nodes is more than a single text node. It may happen for nodes with `isContentEditable === true`, since the user can paste text from Word or other places, or create a new line and so on.

Here's an adaptation of what I did in my framework:

```
var setSelectionRange = function(element, start, end) {
    var rng = document.createRange(),
        sel = getSelection(),
        n, o = 0,
        tw = document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, null);
    while (n = tw.nextNode()) {
        o += n.nodeValue.length;
        if (o > start) {
            rng.setStart(n, n.nodeValue.length + start - o);
            start = Infinity;
        }
        if (o >= end) {
            rng.setEnd(n, n.nodeValue.length + end - o);
            break;
        }
    }
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(rng);
};

var setCaret = function(element, index) {
    setSelectionRange(element, index, index);
};
```

The trick here is to use the `setSelectionRange` function - that selects a range of text inside and element - with `start === end`. In `contentEditable` elements, this puts the caret in the desired position.

This should work in all modern browsers, and for elements that have more than just a text node as a descendant. I'll let you add checks for `start` and `end` to be in the proper range.

For IE8 and lower, things are a little harder. Things would look a bit like this:

```
var setSelectionRange = function(element, start, end) {
    var rng = document.body.createTextRange();
    rng.moveToElementText(element);
    rng.moveStart("character", start);
    rng.moveEnd("character", end - element.innerText.length - 1);
    rng.select();
};
```

The problem here is that `innerText` is *not* good for this kind of things, as some white spaces are collapsed. Things are fine if there's just a text node, but are screwed for something more complicated like the ones you get in `contentEditable` elements.

IE8 doesn't support `textContent`, so you have to count the characters using a `TreeWalker`. But than again IE8 doesn't support `TreeWalker` either, so you have to walk the DOM tree all by yourself...

I still have to fix this, but somehow I doubt I'll ever will. Even if I *did* code a polyfill for `TreeWalker` in IE8 and lower...

Comment: Thanks, I should've mentioned I never got round to the IE8 and lower code. And I never considered people pasting text into the element - I'll have to look into that.

Comment: `setStart()` and `setEnd()` range methods definitely can be used with elements, but the offset represents the number of child nodes of the element prior to the boundary rather than a character index.

Comment: @TimDown Yes, but in Ryan's case it throws an exception, because the second argument is 3 (5 in the fiddle). Thanks for pointing it out, though, it wasn't clear. And I didn't use `collapse` because the function is `setSeletionRange`, which is then called by `setCaret` but it generally creates non-collapsed selections.

Comment: In IE <= 8, why not use TextRange's `moveEnd()` method first? `rng.moveEnd("character", end); rng.moveStart("character", start);`

Comment: @MaxArt: I realised my mistake about `collapse()` and deleted that comment.

Comment: @TimDown IIRC (and I admit my memory is a bit blurry about it) `moveEnd` doesn't work as one expects (as usual from Microsoft's proprietary extensions). It counts the index from the *end* of the text, so you have to give a negative value if you want the selection to end before. I.e. `moveEnd("character", 0)` sets the selection end to the end of the text content of the element.

Comment: @MaxArt: It works just the same as `moveStart()`. If you collapse the TextRange first (which I failed to mention), all is well.

Comment: @TimDown Ah, nice to know this. Anyway, this will be forgotten as soon as IE8 is history (not soon enough, though).

Comment: This breaks when index and text length are equal `setCaret(prev.get(0), prev.text().length)`

Comment: why you have used `end` variable in that? and how to get it?

Comment: The solution seems to be solid but fails when the index is just before (or after) a `<br>` tag.

I know this is old, but has anyone been able to deal with that?

Comment: @keligijus It *shouldn't* fail - although it's been a while since last time I used it. The only edge case that comes in my mind is when the `contentEditable` element contains *just* a `<br>` and no text nodes. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Hey @MaxArt, thanks for your answer. Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q3bhctwv/

It seems that undesired behaviour occurs whenever the cursor is at the end of line.

Comment: @keligijus Ah, pesky little bug... It looks like checking `o >= start` does the trick, but still, if the cursor is at the beginning of a new line, it's brought back to the end of the previous line. That's because, counting text-wise, it's the "same" position... Have fun with some edge cases. :|

Answer (score 1):

Here is my improvement over Tim's answer. It removes the caveat about hidden characters, but the other caveats remain:

- only text nodes are taken into account (line breaks implied by <br> and block elements are not included in the index)
- all text nodes are considered, even those inside elements that are hidden by CSS or inside  elements
- IE <= 8's rules are different again because it uses a different mechanism.

The code:

```
var setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = null;

if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = function(containerEl, start, end) {
        var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

        while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var hiddenCharacters = findHiddenCharacters(node, node.length)
                var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length - hiddenCharacters;

                if (!foundStart && start >= charIndex && start <= nextCharIndex) {
                    var nodeIndex = start-charIndex
                    var hiddenCharactersBeforeStart = findHiddenCharacters(node, nodeIndex)
                    range.setStart(node, nodeIndex + hiddenCharactersBeforeStart);
                    foundStart = true;
                }
                if (foundStart && end >= charIndex && end <= nextCharIndex) {
                    var nodeIndex = end-charIndex
                    var hiddenCharactersBeforeEnd = findHiddenCharacters(node, nodeIndex)
                    range.setEnd(node, nodeIndex + hiddenCharactersBeforeEnd);
                    stop = true;
                }
                charIndex = nextCharIndex;
            } else {
                var i = node.childNodes.length;
                while (i--) {
                    nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
} else if (document.selection) {
    setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = function(containerEl, start, end) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);
        textRange.select();
    };
}

var x = document.getElementById('a')
x.focus()
setSelectionByCharacterOffsets(x, 1, 13)

function findHiddenCharacters(node, beforeCaretIndex) {
    var hiddenCharacters = 0
    var lastCharWasWhiteSpace=true
    for(var n=0; n-hiddenCharacters<beforeCaretIndex &&n<node.length; n++) {
        if([' ','\n','\t','\r'].indexOf(node.textContent[n]) !== -1) {
            if(lastCharWasWhiteSpace)
                hiddenCharacters++
            else
                lastCharWasWhiteSpace = true
        } else {
            lastCharWasWhiteSpace = false   
        }
    }

    return hiddenCharacters
}
```