# Create TextSelection from selection in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selection

I am trying to fix an application in IE11 and I stuck in this bug:  In the older version of IE ther was a simple [selection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx) but it is deprecated in IE11. The MSDN page offer to use getSelection instead of that, but it is not the same. I need to create a [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa741548(v=vs.85).aspx) based on the selection and in the old API there was a simple solution:

```
// there is a TextRange object what I need
var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
```

The new [HTMLSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974359(v=vs.85).aspx) object has no createRange() method and I didn't find any proper solution, what is not modify the DOM.

I try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/p4Lu4/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Lu4/2/) (Usage: Select some text and hit any key. )

The problem with it: If you select throw one of the red boxes, it will remove the box.

Can anyone know a better solution?

**Solution:**

I think, I found a solution. Not the best and nicest but it is working for me: I can create the exact same TextRange from Selection.

http://jsfiddle.net/p4Lu4/4/

**Update 2:**

I create a modul for this: https://gist.github.com/festo/50fe800c7369db140a62

Comment: document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) works for me

Comment: @dandavis: Itt will return a [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772133(v=vs.85).aspx) object, not a [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa741548(v=vs.85).aspx), what I need ...

Comment: the text range you linked to only works on a few elements, not arbitrary selected elements: "You retrieve a TextRange object by using IHTMLBodyElement::createTextRange, IHTMLInputHiddenElement::createTextRange, IHTMLInputTextElement::createTextRange, IHTMLTextAreaElement::createTextRange, or IHTMLButtonElement::createTextRange. " body is weird, but the other ones have a .value and .selectionStart/.selectionEnd properties you can use to manipulate text values.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little bit confused: I thought [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IHTMLTxtRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa741548(v=vs.85).aspx) is the same just the IHTMLTxtRange is a newer version...

Unfortunately, I need to work with the whole body.

Comment: There is Rang-to-TextRange conversion in my [Rangy library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) as part of providing IE < 9 DOM Range and Selection support. I will add methods to expose this conversion more explicitly. Also, Rangy's [`TextRange` module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) has a `findText()` method

Comment: I saw your project on GitHub but I didn't find that kind of solution in it. It will be good if you write more details about it.

Answer (score 2):

My [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) library has code to convert a DOM-compatible range to an IE [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx) as part of providing DOM range and selection support in IE <= 8. The latest build exposes this conversion explicitly on the selection object:

```
var textRange = rangy.getSelection().getNativeTextRange();
```

Note that the `getNativeTextRange()` method of a Rangy selection only exists in IE.

Another alternative is to use Rangy's [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module), which among other things adds an IE-like `findText()` method to Rangy's range object, along with the [class applier module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Class-Applier-Module) to do the highlighting. This will work in all major browsers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sycqeev2/

I'm not sure what's supposed to happen in your demo when you highlight text and press a key, so I haven't attempted to do anything with that.