# How do you get a TextRange object from a user selection in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am struggling to reproduce some code which works in Internet Explorer 10 and earlier, but not in version 11:

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tala/jqs5y0eh/

```
var button = document.getElementById('boldButton');
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('text').focus();
    if (sel = document.selection) {
        range = sel.createRange();
        if (!range.text) {
            range.expand('word');
        }
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
    }
});
```

When the IE console is switched to emulate version 10, this code works fine.

I know that [**selection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx) is no longer supported, so I've tried replacing that with window.getSelection(). With the old selection object, you could call createRange() to get a TextRange object, which gave access to methods like **expand**.

Using getSelection, however, there is no createRange() method. I've tried getRangeAt()

```
if (sel = window.getSelection()) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
```

... but in this case, the range object returned is not a TextRange object and does not implement the expand method.

Any ideas about how this code can be altered to work in IE 11?

Comment: In IE11 you need to use standard properties and methods: [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), the legacy APIs are obsoleted.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. I have tried using standard properties/methods like those you reference on MDN - take this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/tala/oo4qnbt9/ That approach works in FF/Chrome; however, these methods don't work in IE11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create TextSelection from selection in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958043/create-textselection-from-selection-in-ie11)