# how to use insertAtCaret function with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using insertAtCaret function and it works well with a text area.
I'm searching for a solution to change the text area by a content editable div. I changed the text area by a div but it doesn't work.

```
    $(document).ready( function() 
    {
     $('#list li').click(function() { 
      $("#mytextarea").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
      return false
     });
    });

    $.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
     return this.each(function(){
       //IE support
       if (document.selection) {
         this.focus();
         sel = document.selection.createRange();
         sel.text = myValue;
         this.focus();
       }
       //MOZILLA / NETSCAPE support
       else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
         var startPos = this.selectionStart;
         var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
         var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
         this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
         this.focus();
         this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
         this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
         this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
       } else {
         this.value += myValue;
         this.focus();
       }
     });
    };
    #sidediv li{cursor:pointer;}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="sidediv">
        <ul id="list">
          <li>Client first name</li>
          <li>lastname</li>
          <li>username</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <textarea name="mytextarea" id="mytextarea" cols="70" rows="10">Hello!</textarea>
```

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work". What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: sorry my english is very bad, I want to reproduce the same thing with a div, I want to insert the clicked text at a cursor position into the content editable div. but it doesn't do any thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selectionStart and selectionEnd in contenteditable element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288700/selectionstart-and-selectionend-in-contenteditable-element)

Comment: I found this solution [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VzbYJ/32/) , and it does exactly what I want but instead of clicking on button should click on a div, but with the div it insert always the text at the end and not at the cursor position.