# Get highlighted text from div and copy into textarea javascript

Tags: javascript

Managed to get highlighted text from within a textarea and transfer it into another textarea. But when the code is edited so that it gets the highlighted text from within a div instead, it does not work...

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

```
<div id="quote"> load transcript in here instead and grab text from here</div> // does not work

<textarea id="quote" readonly> // works
load transcript in here
</textarea>


<textarea contenteditable="false" id="output" name="selected"></textarea> // outputs highlighted text here


<script>

var quotearea = document.getElementById('quote')
var output = document.getElementById('output')
quotearea.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    if (this.selectionStart != this.selectionEnd){ // check the user has selected some text inside field
        var selectedtext = this.value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd)
        output.innerHTML = selectedtext
    }
}, false)

</script>
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzgyh2kd/

Comment: can you make fiddle for it

Comment: This may give you what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288700/selectionstart-and-selectionend-in-contenteditable-element

Comment: Added a fiddle, checking that link now, looks relevant! Cheers.

Comment: That works Gerardo!! Thank you.

with this updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eLwy4eLp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your question in the comments and deleted it.

You're using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` methods that works only on input elements. For your solution used instead `document.selection.createRange().text` that gets the selected text in the document (inputs, divs, etc., doesn't matter).

Here's the fiddle:

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eLwy4eLp/)

Comment: Thanks mate! The solution makes perfect sense. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI the code in the fiddle just works for the entire document, doesn't use an specific selector, so if you want to use it only in a div that won't work.

Comment: yeah i noticed, if there's a way around that so that it takes from a specific selector that would be cool, otherwise shouldn't be too much of a problem anyway. Kudos.

Comment: Sure, that's possible. You can search here how to create a selectionrange of an specific element and get its content. If you dont find anything I'll send you a fiddle tomorrow morning. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Someone in the comments answered it with a fiddle that had two textarea, but edited one to a div and it seems to work. Cheers. (Edit- turns out a div was not required, it took straight from the page, so a workaround)

```
<div name="" id="original">
Load transcript in here.
</div>

<textarea name="" id="copied" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<script>


var text = '';
function copyText(e) {
    text = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();
    document.getElementById('copied').value = text;
}
document.onmouseup = copyText;
if (!document.all) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
}


</script>
```

Working fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/eLwy4eLp/1/