# Get caret Y position in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting the offset of characters of the caret in a contenteditable div, but this will only return the X offset of the cursor and not the height.

```
         function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
            let caretPosEnd = 0, caretPosStart = 0,
                sel, range;
            if (window.getSelection) {
                sel = window.getSelection();
                if (sel.rangeCount) {
                    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                    if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
                        caretPosEnd = range.endOffset;
                        caretPosStart = range.startOffset;

                        console.log(range);
                        console.log(range.collapse());
                    }
                }
            } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
                range = document.selection.createRange();
                if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
                    var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
                    editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
                    var tempRange = range.duplicate();
                    tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
                    tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
                    caretPosEnd = tempRange.text.length;
                    caretPosStart = caretPosEnd;
                }
            }
            // console.log(caretPosStart, caretPosEnd);
            return {start: caretPosStart, end: caretPosEnd}
        }
```

How can I return both X and Y offset?

Comment: Well, it's not the X pixel location, it's the offset from the beginning in characters, right?  Do you need the location in pixels?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, indeed, I need the offset of characters

Comment: `document.getSelection()` might help you. [selectionStart and selectionEnd in contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288700/selectionstart-and-selectionend-in-contenteditable-element)