# Text highlighting based on positions

Tags: javascript, range, wysiwyg

I have some div with text and spans (include text). How I can highlight text into div if I know highlight positions?
I mean:

```
<div>Lorem<span> ipsum</span> dolor amet</div>
```

for positions 2 and 14:

```
<div>Lo<b>rem<span> ipsum</span> dol</b>or amet</div>
```

I can do this simple? With small and clean code.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16100733/96100

Comment: I know about range. I seek very performance solution for select big number ranges for small time. Range is rewrite DOM on each iteration. I want optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id='mydiv'>Lorem<span> ipsum</span> dolor amet</div>
```

**JS/Jquery**

```
var elm = $('#mydiv');
highlite(elm, 2, 28); //specify the start and end position
 // if you know the word you can find the index of word using indexOf/lastIndexOf

function highlite(element, startpos, endpos) {
    var rgxp = elm.html().substr(startpos,endpos)
    var repl = '<span class="myClass">' + rgxp + '</span>';
    elm.html(elm.html().replace(rgxp, repl));
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/sD2pX/