# How to highlight text based on slice positions and prevail innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanna highlight text in an html element based on start position and end position of the plain text (without html).

For example if we have a sentence "Hello, how are you?"
and I wanted to highlight the word "Hello", the startPos is 0 and endPos is 5.
This is working fine in my code for #text1.

```
<div id="segment">
  <div id="text1">Hello, <b>how</b> are you?</div>
  <div id="text2"><b>Hello</b>, how are you?</div>
</div>

var text1 = document.querySelector('#text1').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('#text1').innerHTML = highlightLetters(text1, 0,5);

function highlightLetters(segmentHTML, startPos, endPos) {
   return "<span style='background-color:pink;'>" + 
   segmentHTML.slice(startPos, endPos) + "</span>" + 
   segmentHTML.slice(endPos);
}
```

The issue is visible in #text2 where the word Hello is wrapped between html  tags. Running highlightLetters() would wrap the highlight span even between html tags.

The expected result after running the highlight function on #text2 should be like this:

```
<div id="text2"><span style='background-color:pink;'><b>Hello</b></span>, how are you?</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwedL6to/1/

Notes:

- My highlight start positions and end positions are coming from an external spellcheck API.
- The #text1 or #text2 could contain really random html tags, so the highlight function needs to be able to deal with it.

similar issue here, but the same problem is there too (unsolved)
[Text highlighting based on positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751664/text-highlighting-based-on-positions)

So perhaps I need a solution which will somehow calculate my new startPos and endPos based on any additional html tags inside the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task is to highlight *single words*, you may combine `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` in combination to achieve the wanted functionality. First you would extract the to be highlighted word using text-only. Then you search for the word's position inside the HTML version to find its location. Now simply swap that part of the string.

**Code:**

```js
var html2 = document.querySelector('#text2').innerHTML;
var text2 = document.querySelector('#text2').innerText;
document.querySelector('#text2').innerHTML = highlightLetters(html2, text2, 0,5);

function highlightLetters(segmentHTML, text, startPos, endPos) {
   var highlightText= text.slice(startPos, endPos);
   var textPosition= segmentHTML.indexOf(highlightText);
   var textLength = endPos - startPos;

   return segmentHTML.slice(0, textPosition) + 
     "<span style='background-color:pink;'>" + 
     segmentHTML.slice(textPosition, textPosition + textLength) + "</span>" + 
     segmentHTML.slice(textPosition + textLength);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/ugw4ko8x/) showing the highlighting.

**Limitations of this version:**

- will not work in case the string to be highlighted contains a closing or opening HTML tag (as `.indexOf()` will not find the string in the HTML)