# Set text selection by source code offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I set a **text selection** in a contenteditable div based on the position in the source code?

An example:

I've got the following html source code for a html element:

```
A sentence <div>with <span class='foo'><b>html</b>&nbsp;content</span>!</div>
```

This sentence has 77 characters. How can I make a selection of the word `content` with the function call `setSelection(parentDiv, 56, 63)`. So I'm searching for a solution for this:

```
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");

function setSelection(parentDiv, start, end) {
    // how can I set the selection?
}

setSelection(editor, 16, 21); // this should select "with"
setSelection(editor, 56, 63); // this should select "content"
```

[Javascript Contenteditable - set Cursor / Caret to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095155/javascript-contenteditable-set-cursor-caret-to-index#16100733) goes in the right direction, but there only the characters of text nodes will be count.

Only modern browsers will be supported (IE >= 9) and the use of jQuery (or other libraries) is also possible.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKcLe/).