# Set cursor/selection for contenteditable div

Tags: google-chrome, browser, selection, contenteditable

Setting focus is simple enough: `node.focus()`. I've had limited success looking at other answers. I can set the cursor at either the beginning or end, or I can select the whole contents with this code in chrome:

```
// if start==0 means the beginning, start===1 means the end
function setSelection(node, start, length) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(node, start);
    range.setEnd(node, length);
    //range.collapse(true);

    var selection = getSelection()
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

So the question is: how can I set the cursor more granularly, say at character 2. Also, how can I set the selection, for example from character 2 to character 5?

[MDN tells me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.setStart) that `Range.setStart` has different behavior for Text, Comment, or CDATASection nodes than other nodes. If I could get setStart to treat a `div` like a Text node, I think my problem might be solved.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16100733/96100

Comment: I have seen that answer already. It is not the same question I'm asking. In fact, I explicitly say in my question this is about non-Text nodes.

Comment: In which case you need to read that answer again. It does exactly what you want, with a few caveats.

Comment: Ah, in first testing it seemed not to work because of the hidden whitespace caveat. Thanks.