# Set pointer to contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

How I can set pointer to contenteditable div using JavaScript ?
Something like this: `$('[contenteditable="true"]').setCursor(10);`

Comment: What do you mean with 'set pointer'? Give focus to the div? Move the mouse cursor to the div? Change the mouse cursor shape when hovering over the div? Please edit and improve your question.

Comment: I think you may want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095155/javascript-contenteditable-set-cursor-caret-to-index

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet that may help you. You can find working example [here http://jsfiddle.net/naveen_champ/wps4cn01/](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen_champ/wps4cn01/)

UPDATE: Code updated [on 02-Oct-2014] after Tim comments, to match support content editable elements.

```
!function($){   
    function findHiddenCharacters(node, beforeCaretIndex) {
        var hiddenCharacters = 0
        var lastCharWasWhiteSpace=true
        for(var n=0; n-hiddenCharacters<beforeCaretIndex &&n<node.length; n++) {
            if([' ','\n','\t','\r'].indexOf(node.textContent[n]) !== -1) {
                if(lastCharWasWhiteSpace)
                    hiddenCharacters++
                else
                    lastCharWasWhiteSpace = true
            } else {
                lastCharWasWhiteSpace = false   
            }
        }

        return hiddenCharacters
    }
    var setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = null;

    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = function(containerEl, start, end) {
            var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
            range.collapse(true);
            var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

            while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
                if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                    var hiddenCharacters = findHiddenCharacters(node, node.length)
                    var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length - hiddenCharacters;

                    if (!foundStart && start >= charIndex && start <= nextCharIndex) {
                        var nodeIndex = start-charIndex
                        var hiddenCharactersBeforeStart = findHiddenCharacters(node, nodeIndex)
                        range.setStart(node, nodeIndex + hiddenCharactersBeforeStart);
                        foundStart = true;
                    }
                    if (foundStart && end >= charIndex && end <= nextCharIndex) {
                        var nodeIndex = end-charIndex
                        var hiddenCharactersBeforeEnd = findHiddenCharacters(node, nodeIndex)
                        range.setEnd(node, nodeIndex + hiddenCharactersBeforeEnd);
                        stop = true;
                    }
                    charIndex = nextCharIndex;
                } else {
                    var i = node.childNodes.length;
                    while (i--) {
                        nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (document.selection) {
        setSelectionByCharacterOffsets = function(containerEl, start, end) {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
            textRange.collapse(true);
            textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
            textRange.moveStart("character", start);
            textRange.select();
        };
    }


    $.fn.setCaretPosition = function(caretPos) {
        return this.each(function(){
            var elem = this;
            setSelectionByCharacterOffsets(elem, caretPos, caretPos);
        });
    }
}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: That code is for text `<input>`s and `<textarea>`s, not `contenteditable`.