# Parameters required to reconstruct Range object creation

Tags: javascript, range

I am doing a simple thing but facing various challenges along with it .All I wanna do is to store all required range object parameters inorder to reconstruct user selection. Currently I am storing id of start and endContainer and start and `endOffset`.But these params seems to be not enough as in case user selection spans to any childNodes within the start/endContainer its offset is calculated relative to that childNode and not start/endContainer id. So can anyone help me to figure out what all or extra params I would need to unqiuely identify my selection i.e `nextSibling` ,`previousSibling` of container etc ??

My current code for regenration of range object here is :-

```
function buildRange(startOffset, endOffset, startContainerId, endContainerId){

    var startContainer = document.getElementById(startContainerId);    
    var endContainer = document.getElementById(endContainerId);
    // create the range    
    var range = document.createRange();   
    range.setStart(startContainer.firstChild, startOffset);
    range.setEnd(endContainer.firstChild, endOffset);

    return range;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/96100 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095155/javascript-contenteditable-set-cursor-caret-to-index/16100733#16100733

Comment: Thanks alot @Tim Down for replying. My purpose/usecase is rather simple and I guess commonly used by people. I wanna add comments on selected portion of HTML file . For this User will select some content on HTML file .and a Dialog will pop up to input comment text.Once dialog is submitted the user selection and comment text is stored in DB. As soon as dialog gets disposed , I wanna highlight the user selection and wanna show comment text on top of highlighted portion ( something like clickable mouse tooltip or something.)

Comment: I went through your rangy wiki and found pretty much the work I wanna do.Currently I have used the serialiser module to gather and serialise the user selection and storing the same in DB .Now when I am applying classApplier module on the selected selection to highlight the selection it isn't working as desired.I observed if I am calling this classApplier in the same window where txt is selected (i.e without passing any window reference to the method it works fine).But since I am calling this method from a different window ( passing the correct window reference also) its not working as desired.

Comment: AddComment.js -$(document).ready(function() {rangy.init();
    var serializerModule = rangy.modules.Serializer;   
     var addCommentBtn = gEBI("AddComment");
     addCommentBtn.disabled = false;
     addCommentBtn.ontouchstart = addCommentBtn.onclick = serializeSelection;
function serializeSelection() {
    var serialisedSelection = rangy.serializeSelection();
    sessionStorage.setItem("serialisedSelection", serialisedSelection);
    showCommentDialog("comment");
}

Comment: postComments.js -  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "comment",
     data: "serialisedSelection=" + sessionStorage.getItem("serialisedSelection") + "&artifactUUID=" + sessionStorage.getItem("artifactUUID") + "&type=" + $("#_type").val()+
     "&disposition="+ $("#_disp").val()+"&description="+ tinyMCE.get('commText').getContent(),     
     success: function(response){var commentModel = JSON.parse(response); var serialisedString = commentModel.serialisedSelection; rangy.deserializeSelection(serialisedString,window);rangy.restoreSelectionFromCookie(); applier.applyToSelection(window); },