# Set caret position in span in contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, position, contenteditable, caret

I have this setup:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <span>The quick brown fox </span>
    <span>jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
</div>
```

I need to be able to set the caret somewhere inside a span. 
I have found this [How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div) which makes me able to set it inside a div, but not inside a span in the div.

Making the spans themselves contenteditable works, but I don't want that, because that way I lose the possibility to select over multiple spans.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095155/javascript-contenteditable-set-cursor-caret-to-index

Comment: Hey @TimDown thanks for the link. It looks as your solution works with each subelement as a sepereate contenteditable, right?

I want to avoid that, cause I want to be able to make selections over several subelements.

Comment: No, the nested elements need not be contenteditable. However, I may have misunderstood exactly what you're asking. How exactly do you want to place the caret?

Comment: I am using the spans for styling. So I could end up with something like this:
    <div contenteditable="true">
        <span style="color:red">The quick brown fox </span>
        <span style="color:green">jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
    </div>

But the user would still need be able to select "fox jumps" and I need to be able to put the caret anywhere in any span (or over multiple spans)

Comment: I did have a closer look at the linked examples and indeed they work as well with spans. Thanks!