# Set selection by range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, range, textselection

I want to select text by sending location/anchorOffset and length/offset using Javascript Here is my code

```
  var node = document.getElementById("content");
   var range = document.createRange();
   range.setStart(node, 0);
   range.setEnd(node, 4); // here 0 and 4 is my location and length for the selection
       // if my string is "This is test string" in my case its must select "This" 
   var selection = window.getSelection();
   selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
```

But the issue is with range.setStart and range.setEnd its not working as I expect

Comment: @AndyG I am using it in my IOS app.Remaining function are working okay but the issue is only with setStart and setEnd both are not working

Comment: @AndyG: Wrong way round. `document.createRange()` is the standard, supported by everything except IE <= 8.

Comment: Thank you @TimDown. I was looking at `selection.createRange`.

Comment: Check this link: https://javascript.info/selection-range

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `setStart()` and `setEnd()` methods of DOM Range are well specified, so you could find the answer by reading [the spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-range-setstart) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.setStart).

To summarise, if you want to specify a range boundary in terms of character offsets, you need to deal with a text node rather than an element. If your element contains a single text node, changing the first line of your code to the following will work:

```
var node = document.getElementById("content").firstChild;
```

Comment: Great It working in the case if I have only one text line in the "content". What about if I have applied bold or font tag on the string.

Comment: @ShinningRiver: Then you'll need a more complicated solution, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/96100

Answer (score 19):

Here's a good solution if you're trying to select a jquery result set

```
var $newSelection = $('.someElements');
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStartBefore($newSelection.first()[0]);
range.setEndAfter($newSelection.last()[0]);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```