# Can't restore selection after HTML modify, even if it's the same HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, selection, contenteditable

I'm trying to store a selection of a contentEditable element and restore it later.

I want to observe the `paste` event and store the HTML as it was before, clear the html and then manually insert the pasted text with some changes at the selected position.

Take a look at this example: [jsfiddle.net/gEhjZ](http://jsfiddle.net/gEhjZ/)

When you select a part of the text, hit `store`, remove the selection again and hit `restore`, it's working as expected.

But when you first hit `store`, then replace the HTML with the exact same HTML by hitting `overwrite html` and then try to `restore`, nothing happens.

I thought that using `.cloneRange()` would make a difference, but it won't. Even a deep copy of the object (`$.extend(true, {}, oldRange)`) won't do the trick. As soon as I overwrite the HTML, the selection object `sel` is being changed too. It makes sense for me that changing the selection context will wipe the range, but I'm trying to restore it for the exact same HTML.

I know I could use [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/), but I really don't want to use a huge library just for this small feature. What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated!

**Note:** only Firefox/Chrome, so no crossbrowser-hacks needed.

## Update:

@Tim Down's answer works when using a div, but I'm actually using an iframe. When I made that example, I thought it wouldn't make any difference.

Now when I try to restore the iframe's body, i get the following error: `TypeError: Value does not implement interface Node.` in the following line `preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);`. I didn't get much from googling. I tried to wrap the contents of the body and restore the wrap's html, but I get the same error.

jsfiddle isn't working in this case because it is using iframes to display the results itself, so I put an example here: [snipt.org/AJad3](http://snipt.org/AJad3)

And the same without the wrap: [snipt.org/AJaf0](http://snipt.org/AJaf0)

**Update 2:**
I figured that I have to use `editable.get(0)`, of course. But now the `start` and `end` of the iframe's selection is 0. see [snipt.org/AJah2](http://snipt.org/AJah2)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could save and restore the character position using functions like these:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/96100

I've adapted these function slightly to work for an element inside an iframe.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/gEhjZ/4/

Code:

```
var saveSelection, restoreSelection;

if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView;
        var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
        preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + range.toString().length
        };
    };

    restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView;
        var charIndex = 0, range = doc.createRange();
        range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

        while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                    foundStart = true;
                }
                if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                    stop = true;
                }
                charIndex = nextCharIndex;
            } else {
                var i = node.childNodes.length;
                while (i--) {
                    nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        var sel = win.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    };
} else if (document.selection) {
    saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
        var selectedTextRange = doc.selection.createRange();
        var preSelectionTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
        var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
        };
    };

    restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
        var textRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
        textRange.select();
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the range is now saved properly but somehow it silently fails to restore the selection. http://snipt.org/AJaj0

Comment: @koko: Possibly the iframe document isn't fully loaded when the initial script runs. I'd suggest `$('iframe').contents().find('body')[0]` instead of `editable.get(0)` inside your click handlers.

Comment: The document is definetely fully loaded, I'm calling this function on the `paste` event. However, the `doc` variable is undefined (`containerEl.ownerDocument`). Chrome just doesn't mind about it, while Firefox does. I will take a look at this later, I guess the rest will be relatively easy to resolve.

Comment: @koko: `containerEl.ownerDocument` being undefined indicates that something is wrong with `containerEl`, such as having been removed from the document.

Comment: Got it now, I had to hardcode some selectors and do `var sel = win.getSelection();` instead of `window.getSelection()`. Just noticed that you are that rangy guy :) I guess you took the code from rangy and forgot to replace this piece. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @koko: Ah yes, I missed a `window` there. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: There is a limitation though i guess. Placing the cursor at the beginning of next empty line and save selection and while restoring selection it places the cursor at the end of previous line. Is there a way to overcome it ??

Answer (score 1):

Provided solution works very well.

replacing that line

```
if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
```

by

```
if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start < nextCharIndex) {
```

prevents Chrome / Edge to select the end of the previous line