# How can I replace hash tag on keydown event like twitter or facebook. javascript // jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, range, keydown

I have contentEditable element(maybe div...) and I would like to replace hash tag or url like twitter(or facebook) on keydown event.

I can normally archieve it with this below..

```
    //onKeydown Event
    ....

    _this.saveRange();   // save current range

    var string = _this.getHtml();    //_this is contentEditable element (div)

    var reg = /(:?#{1}|\s#{1})([A-Za-z0-9.;_\-ㄱ-ㅎ|ㅏ-ㅣ|가-힣]+)/gm;

    if(reg.test(string)) {
        var text = string.replace(reg, function(u) {
            return '<a class="highlight" rel="external" id="test">' + u + '</a>';
        });

        _this.setHtml(text);    // insert html what replaced using innerHtml 

        _this.restoreRange();

    }
```

This works fine replace text.. on keydown event.

But when I set html that replaced, document range(cursor) is move first position.

this is problem.

I saved range before innerHtml and restore range after innerHtml. But it doesn't work.

Below that I used function saveRange and restoreRange.

```
    var savedRange;   //public variable

    function saveRange() {
        if(window.getSelection) {
            savedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        } else if(document.selection) {  //IE
            savedRange = document.selection.createRange();
        }
    }    



     function restoreRange() {
            if (savedRange != null) {
                    if (window.getSelection)//non IE and there is already a selection
                    {
                        var s = window.getSelection();
                        if (s.rangeCount > 0) 
                            s.removeAllRanges();
                        s.addRange(savedRange);
                    }
                    else if (document.createRange)//non IE and no selection
                    {
                        window.getSelection().addRange(savedRange);
                    }
                    else if (document.selection)//IE
                    {
                        savedRange.select();
                    }
                }
         }
```

Can anybody come up with solution to this ???
or give me a link.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save and restore the selection range by character index so long as the text content is remaining the same. I've provided simple functions to do this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17694760/96100

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I replaced hash tag like this ex ->  <a><s>#</s>test</a>&nbsp;  and cursor is end of "test" text. and I want to make a cursor exit </a> tag when I press the spacebar. but it doesn't work;; cursor still is in <a> tag.  I don't know how I can fix it. plz give me a solution or link...  and I'm sorry I can't Vote Up because I have 10 reputation.. ;;