# re-set caret in contentEditable after value has changed

Tags: javascript, selection

> ### [Demo Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/UuYQH/184/)
>
> *(Try to write something in the demo and see this unwanted behaviour)*

A `div` content can be changed when user is typing in it, and the text is evaluated and some words get marked (wrapper element), so the HTML of the `div` is changed and user is loosing the caret position.

I can know what the caret offset was just before the HTML change, but I don't know how to **restore the caret** to that place, once the HTML has changed, the Range object means nothing...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solution** - http://jsfiddle.net/UuYQH/194/

I've found somewhere online a `save` & `load` methods for selection and incorporated them in my code and it works great!

Comment: Thanks, your `save` and `load` caret position functions are awesome.

Comment: @TimDown - there is a bug in your caret saving method, try to delete a character (without selecting it): http://jsfiddle.net/T6yLs/1/

Comment: @TimDown - you probably use Chrome. I use FF, and it gives [0,0] upon deletion.

Comment: You're right, there seems to be a bug. I've written simpler code to do this since, so rather than try and debug the old code, here's your fiddle with the newer code, taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/96100. http://jsfiddle.net/T6yLs/3/