# Linkify in Textarea Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, froala

I am using [linkify](https://github.com/SoapBox/jQuery-linkify) in textarea & i have autosave function in it.
After every 3 secs the text is saved in `database` .I am calling linkify before saving in `database`.

```
$(".froala-element").linkify();
```

What problem i am facing is the focus of cursor/caret is lost due to linkify ..

I keep on writing and after autosave cursor is lost its position..
I am using froala-editor as my text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the caret position before you run the linkify/db-save, and then restore the caret position after its done. An example of how to store and restore caret positions is provided here:

[Persisting the changes of range objects after selection in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949059/persisting-the-changes-of-range-objects-after-selection-in-html/13950376#13950376)

Comment: it worked but still i have some issues .. cursor is not smooth as it should be

Comment: can you be more specific about what you mean with "not smooth"?

Comment: some lag is occuring while the ajax is called

Comment: well, im not sure how your code looks etc, but if it is: save caret - linkify - store to db - restore caret. Then you culd maybe try to swap the order to restore the caret after the linkify. You will have to research what is causing the lag etc

Comment: Thanks zedd i tried few combination .. Finally Savecaret- Linkify - RestoreCaret - SavetoDB worked for me .