# binding textContent and overriding dom with svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a `div` with `contenteditable=true` and `bind:textContent={value}` so it behaves pretty much like a textarea.

The only issue I have with it is that I want to override the content of the `div` by processing the `value`, but seems like it is not possible.

To test I wrote this

```
<div contenteditable="true" bind:textContent={value}>testVal</div>
```

where `value` is an exported property of the component.

I kind of expected `value` to be set to `testVal`, but instead the div contains the `value` property.

I sort of understand why this is happening and that what I am doing is sort of an edge case, but is it at all possible to change this behaviour to kind of get a one way binding to `value`?

and I have tried my "normal" way of creating a one way binding (with some hacks to demonstrate issues):

```
<div contenteditable="true" on:input={e => value = e.target.textContent}>
  {#each (value || "").split("") as part}
    {part}
  {/each}
</div>
```

this looks fine, but whenever I change type in the div my input gets multiplied, i.e. if I type `e` the div gets updated with `ee`. If I add another `e` I get `eeee`

Comment: Maybe a silly question but did you see that the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/contenteditable-bindings) says for `contenteditable` you can `bind:innerHTML={value}`

Comment: I have seen that tutorial, but I might be missing something. That tutorial is quite easy as it is not manipulating the content of the editable div. (i.e. it keeps the output separate). imagine that I want to write <b>bold</b> and have the editable div update and set it to bold

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you're trying to solve. So should the user be able to type something and then, based on what he/she typed, the text just typed gets changed immediately? What kind of changes would you like to happen? Is it just formatting?

Comment: exactly, the typed text should get changed immediately. and yes it will just be formatting, my first use case is to use it for a hacky syntax highlighting and change colors of text sort of "on the fly"

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go is to use your "normal" way of creating a one way binding. Otherwise, using multiple ways of binding on the same element will conflict.

I used a combination of `on:input` like you described and, inside of the `div`, `{@html html}`

The following example formats each other word in bold as you type (there's some glitch when starting with an empty field):

```html
<script>
    import {tick} from "svelte";
    let html = '<p>Write some text!</p>';

    // for the implementation of the two functions below, see 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/4262276
    let saveSelection = (containerEl) => { /**/ };
    let restoreSelection = (containerEl, savedSel) => { /**/ };

    let editor;

    function handleInput(e){
        const savedSelection = saveSelection(editor);
        html = e.target.textContent
            .split(" ")
            .map((t, i) => i % 2 === 0 
                ? `<span style="font-weight:bold">${t}</span>` 
                : t
            )
            .join(" ");
        tick().then(() => { 
            restoreSelection(editor, savedSelection);
        })
    }
</script>

<div
    bind:this={editor}
    contenteditable="true"
    on:input={handleInput}
>{@html html}</div>


<style>
    [contenteditable] {
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>
```